# How do I update a message to show a venue in Telegram?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot. I want to update a message so that the text will be replaced by a venue object.
When I call sendVenue with the message id in 'reply_to_message_id', telegram creates a new message with the venue, instead of updating the existing one.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the requests:

**sendMessage:**

REQUEST:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{{telegram-token}}/sendMessage
{
    "chat_id" : ..., 
    "text" : "my text",
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "message_id": 247,
        "from": {
            "id": 123456,
            "is_bot": true,
            "first_name": "...",
            "username": "..."
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": ...,
            "title": "...",
            "type": "supergroup"
        },
        "date": 1546552248,
        "text": "my text"
    }
}
```

**Update message into a venue:**

REQUEST:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{{telegram-token}}/sendVenue
{
    "chat_id" : "...", 
    "longitude" : -74.8354,
    "latitude": 40.13817,
    "title" : "my title",
    "address" : "my address",
    "disable_notification" : true,
    "reply_to_message_id" : 247
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram Bot API doesn't allow bots to update messages from one type to another. You can change the content of the text message to another text. But you cannot change text message to a venue.

The only thing you can do is to delete the old message and send new containing venue.

So you can do like this:

```
> Send text message
> Delete it
> Send venue
```

But sending and deleting the text message doesn't make sense.